# if Cell is Blank then clear content of another cell Code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In My sheet when I update Cells in D column the Cell in C column will show date of update , now I need if I delete the info in D cell to Delete the info in C cell not as formula as VBA code 
Code below :

```
 `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   With Target.Offset(0, -1)
    .Value = Now
     .NumberFormat = " MM/DD/YY hh:mm Am/PM"
  End With

   Dim RangeA As Range
   Set RangeA = Range("D10:D10000")
    If Application.CountBlank(RangeA) = RangeA.Cells.Count Then
    Range("C10:C10000").ClearContents
     End If
     End Sub`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend adding an `if-statement` to support your activities, such that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> "" then
        With Target.Offset(0, -1) 
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = " MM/DD/YY hh:mm Am/PM"
        End With
    Else
        Target.Offset(,-1).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Aboudezoua wonderful; please mark as your answer (the check mark left of my post) if this has resolved your issue.